# How could I display a text on the same line?

Tags: ruby

I accept text input from a user. When I use the received text within a line as follows,

```
puts "whats your name?"
$name = STDIN.gets
puts "Oh #$name, nice to meet you"
```

it is displayed on a separate line. It puts the name and then the `"nice to meet you"` on a new line.

Is there a way to fix this? Also if you see something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: You can usually omit `STDIN` and just call [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), i.e. without a receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `gets` without any option receives the input including the terminating end of line. If you simply interpolate that as a part of a string, that end of line will be printed as a line break.

To avoid line break, pass the parameter `chomp` with value `true` to `gets`:

```
$name = STDIN.gets(chomp: true)
```

In the old school way, apply `chomp` after `gets` like:

```
$name = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

`chomp` removes white space characters from the end of the string, thus it avoids the line break.

Other things wrong about your code are:

- You missed to capitalize the sentence `whats your name?`.
- You missed an apostrophe in `whats`.
- You should avoid using a global variable like `$name`. Try using another type of variable.
- You missed a period at the end of the sentence `Oh #$name, nice to meet you`.

Comment: _"Apply chomp after gets"_ – maybe you can briefly explain why the text is displayed on two lines and what `chomp` does to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing that global variable to a local variable. If you do, you'll have to change the way you interpolate.

Also, I would suggest using the `gets.chomp` method and leave out `STDIN`.

Example:

```rb
puts "What's your name?"
name = gets.chomp 
puts "Oh, #{name}, nice to meet you."
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "regular" variable. There is no strangeness to variables.

Answer (score 0):

- `gets` is used to input data from the user and includes a line break at the end.
- `chomp` is used to return and store data as a string value.

  ```
  $name = STDIN.gets.chomp
  ```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by your second point. What you pointed out as what `chomp` is doing is actually what `gets` does.

Comment: You can refer to following documentation https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html